# grade 2 ideals and zero divisors

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose I have a short exact sequence, with I an ideal and R a polynomial ring over C:

$ 0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow aI \rightarrow \frac{aI}{I} \rightarrow 0$

where $ a \in R$ and the first nontrivial map is multiplication by a. If I and aI are of grade 2, why must a be a unit in R?

My instinct is to use long exact sequences in ext to gain isomorphisms of hom( , ) but I cannot make that very useful.

Comment: If $J\subset aR$, then $J$ has grade always at most one, unless $a$ is a unit.

Comment: Could you clarify what means $aI/I$? Thanks.